# How to get null as a property value using @Value in spring

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot

This is my straight forward question as there is very little context to it.

I spring boot app with application.properties

```
allowedValues=Hello, Hi, null
```

and I am reading the values in my spring component as follows

```
@Value("${allowedValues}")
private String[] allowedGreetings;
```

When I run this, the values in `allowedGreetings` array are as expected `("Hello", "Hi", "null")`

But what I want is a way to get the array as `("Hello", "Hi", null)`

As you can see, I can't set the default value for `allowedGreetings` to null because I want read null as a member of array.

This is to avoid writing a function to read the array and convert `"null"` to `null` in the array. Is there a possible way in spring ?

Comment: What happens if you use a `List<String>`?

Comment: Also, have you tried using `@ConfigurationProperties` instead?

Comment: How about `allowedValues=Hello, Hi,`?

Comment: Thanks for the comments. List<String> just loads it as one string with commas in it. and "allowedValues=Hello,Hi, " reads as three strings with empty string in the third. I havent tried @ConfigurationProperties yet.

Answer (score 0):

I have a class like this

```
package tuladhar.aman;
@Component // @Service , @Controller etc
public class Application {}
```

Created the static method `parseProperties` and `parseString`. 
Used the SpEL to call the method

`"#{T(tuladhar.aman.Application).parseProperties('${allowedValues}')}"`

```
    public static List<String> parseProperties(String[] array) {
        return Stream
            .of(array)
            .map(Application::parseString)
            .collect(Collectors.toList());
    }

    public static  String parseString(String s){
        return "null".equals(s) ? null : s;
    }

    @Value("#{T(tuladhar.aman.Application).parseProperties('${allowedValues}')}")
    private List<String> allowedValues;
```

Comment: I was actually trying to avoid a custom method to parse "null" to null.

Comment: I don't know if that kind of feature is built in.